# How to allow access to a file for a specific domain and block for other domain in Apache2.conf?

Tags: apache, apache2

I have blocked the access to a file in apache configuration by editing the .conf file. For now, only localhost can access the files. Is there a way where i can access the files if it requested from a specific domain name or if requested by query string parameters.

Apache.conf -

> Order allow,deny
>                   Allow from 127.0.0.1

Comment: What do you mean saying "domain"? A virtual host name or visitor's host name? If second, [here are docs you need](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow).

Comment: i mean allow access from www.example.com

Comment: You should build a virtualhost on /etc/apache2/sites enabled and giving Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.example.com". Look at [this example](https://github.com/AndreaM16/UnicApp-1.0/blob/master/app/apache2/apache2Serverconfig), I Also used Proxypass, ProxyReverse and Aliases.